# I lost my Italian residence permit abroad, how can I obtain a duplicate so that I can fly back to Italy?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, italy, lost-documents, permesso-di-soggiorno

Sweden is going to ban me from flying if I can't show them my lost permesso di soggiorno from Italy. It was issued in Florence because my old one expired while I was in school. How do I get a copy?

Comment: Call the Italian consulate or embassy nearest you in Sweden.

Answer (score 13):

You lost your *permesso di soggiorno* (Italian residency permit), whilst on a trip abroad. You now wish to return to Italy and are afraid you won't be allowed to fly back to Italy. The solution is to **report the lost permit to the local authorities to obtain an official statement**. You should then **take this statement to [your local Italian mission](http://www.ambstoccolma.esteri.it/ambasciata_stoccolma) and ask for a *visto di reingresso*** i.e. a re-entry visa. The Italian mission will contact the police commissioner of the  city in which the residency permit was issued, and perform some other checks prior to issuing the re-entry visa. The quote below (in Italian) comes from [a governmental website (Linea Amica)](http://www.lineaamica.gov.it/risposte/smarrimento-o-furto-allestero-titolo-soggiorno) and rougly states exactly what I paraphrased:

> ### Smarrimento o furto all'estero del titolo di soggiorno
>
> #### Domanda:
>
> Se si smarrisce o viene rubato il permesso di soggiorno mentre si è all'estero, come fare per rientrare in Italia?
>
> #### Risposta:
>
> Ai sensi dell'art. 8 comma 2 del [Decreto del Presidente della Repubblica 394 del 1999](http://www.normattiva.it/uri-res/N2Ls?urn:nir:stato:decreto.legge:1999-08-31;394!vig=), in caso di smarrimento o furto del titolo di soggiorno all'estero in corso di validità, dovrà esser presentata alle autorità diplomatiche una richiesta di visto di reingresso per titolare di permesso di soggiorno, allegando l'apposita denuncia di smarrimento o furto e si dovrà attendere la verifica del Consolato italiano sul titolo stesso.
>
> La richiesta di visto di reingresso si presenta appunto presso le autorità diplomatico-consolari italiane del Paese estero, mentre la denuncia di smarrimento o furto del permesso di soggiorno o passaporto presso le autorità di pubblica sicurezza del luogo.
>
> Il visto di reingresso e' rilasciato  previa  verifica  dell'esistenza  del  provvedimento  del questore concernente il soggiorno.
>
> In caso di problemi con la Rappresentanza consolare locale è possibile contattare l'Ufficio Relazioni con il Pubblico URP del Ministero degli Esteri compilando l'apposito modulo, indicando la problematica riscontrata.

It is not uncommon for airlines to allow passengers to fly inside of Schengen with just the photocopy of their residence permit and a copy of the police statement. Nevertheless it is wiser to follow the official procedure, rather than to bet on airline leniency.

Comment: It is not uncommon for airlines to allow passengers to fly inside of Schengen without ever looking at their passports at all.  I guess something else happened in this case, or Sweden has some new rules in effect.

Comment: Schengen is basically a single Country for border purposes, so except for low-cost carriers, unless you check in baggage you normally don't Need to Show ID, only your Boarding pass

Comment: @Crazydre I'm sorry but you are wrong. You need to show id when boarding intra schengen flights. Not for immigration purposes but to check if you are really the owner of the plane ticket.

Comment: I've flown many times with with Swiss, KLM, Air France, Lufthansa, Alitalia, Austrian Airlines and Iberia. **Never** had to Show ID at the gate - I know it does happen though, hence why I said "normally"